# Why this concurrent objective-c code crash

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            self.str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"asgdhjagsjhd"];
        });
}
```

}

every time I run this code,it will crash,can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You should keep your queue outside of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used **self.str** with **nonatomic** property,
then it will be accessed and modified by all thread,
i checked this above code, which is crashing cause is releasing object by one thread while other thread is try to access it,
because of **release** that object it crashing.
if you want to use **thread safe** then please make **atomic** property of **self.str**.

Comment: This answer is completely misleading.  Atomic properties have nothing to do with thread safety.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1